# How is "social media accounts" translated?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico

I want to say:

> The court allowed the defense to use a photo from the woman's **social media accounts**.

And have translated it as:

> El tribunal permitió a la defensa utilizar una foto de la **cuenta de redes sociales** de la mujer.

I can't find anywhere an actual translation of "social media accounts" and wonder if I'm being too literal. Is my translation of it correct?

Answer (score 5):

[@Txortx's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/34574/1674) sounds good, alternatively you could drop the "cuenta" bit:

> El tribunal permitió a la defensa utilizar una foto de las redes sociales de la mujer.

Answer (score 2):

La traducción que se acostumbra a usar para social media es «redes sociales».

Se traduciría como: La corte permitió que la defensa usase una foto de una de sus cuentas en una red social

Answer (score 2):

*"El tribunal permitió a la defensa utilizar una foto de la cuenta de redes sociales de la mujer".*

A mi me suena perfectamente bien. Lo único que cambiaría sería el "**la** cuenta" por "**una** cuenta", ya que es un artículo indeterminado. No sabemos a qué cuenta nos estamos refiriendo exactamente, y seguramente no importa.

Por tanto, "social media account(s)" is translated as "cuenta(s) de redes sociales".